# Update first rows that match condition

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

```
Update table1
set column1 = 'abc', column2 = 25
where column3 IN ('John','Kate','Tim')
```

Column3 contains John twice (two associated rows/records), similarly - it has Kate third times and Tim twice.
How can I adjust the query so that the update affects only the first row with John, the first row with Kate and the first with Tim?

For the reference, here is table1:

```
column1 column2 column3
aa       2       John (!)
affd     24      John 
dfd      5       Tim (!)
ss       77      Kate (!)
s        4       Tim
s        1       Kate
sds      34      Kate
```

I want to update only the rows marked with (!)

I am especially interested in Ms Access! - but also curious how this is done in Sql Server in case it differs. Thank you!

Comment: In SQL Server 2005+, a CTE and a ROW_NUMBER call could probably be used, although you would still need to know what determines the row's "firstness". I have no idea how this could be solved in MS Access.

Answer (score 5):

Sql Server solution - Note, you must have a unique identity column for this to work (or some set of unique columns).

```
UPDATE table1 
SET    column1 = 'abc', 
       column2 = 25 
WHERE  id IN (SELECT id 
              FROM   (SELECT id, 
                             Row_number() 
                               OVER ( 
                                 ORDER BY rowyouwanttoorderby ) AS ROWNUM 
                      FROM   table1 
                      WHERE  column3 IN ( 'John', 'Kate', 'Tim' )) AS temp 
              WHERE  rownum = 1)
```